# Can I force g++ to pass floating number arguments on the stack?

Tags: c++, assembly, g++

In order to implement a C#-like invoke method, I need to combine C++ code with assembly. But I ran into troubles when I passed floating point numbers to it, finding that those arguments are passed with some floating point instructions.

So is there any way to force g++ to use the common stack(esp)? Thanks.

Comment: Are they not passed on stack, but on registers?

Comment: @PetrBudnik, it depends on your ABI and calling conventions. Most x86 ABIs pass them on the FPU stack. Most x86_64 ABIs pass them in SSE registers.

Comment: Also, this reeks of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/). There may very well be a simpler solution if you can provide more context.

Comment: @zneak But If I take address of the passed variable? Compiler has to spill it on stack.

Comment: @PetrBudnik, I'm not sure I understand your remark. The variable has to exist in addressable memory if you get its address for sure, but that's not related to calling conventions. When emitting a function call, the compiler doesn't care if the variable exists or not on the stack: it needs to pass the value in a known way so that the called function can retrieve it.

Comment: @zneak, yeah maybe I've sunk deeply into it. Here is the circumstance: I'm working with FLTK and created a drawing thread for it. It provides two method to perform drawing in another thread: One is using lock() and unlock(), which I don't prefer. Another is call the awake() function to post a call to the drawing thread, but this requires the function to be void( * )(void * ). So I want to make it more flexible.

Comment: @user1778496 How would you call that `Invoke`-like function?

Comment: @zneak, it's like this: void Invoke(void*proc,int argnum, ...). This function wraps all its arguments in a struct, and then call awake() with the struct pointer and a function pointer to an "agent". The agent is written in assembly and will do the final call in the drawing thread.

Comment: -1 because you didn't provide any code, let alone an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) or any evidence of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, I think you're basically trying to do what can be achieved using the type-safe functionality offered by `std::function` and `std::bind` (from C++11).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(int x, double y, float z)
{
    cout << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << endl;
}

void call_agent(void* pointer)
{
    function<void()>* wrapper = reinterpret_cast<function<void()>*>(pointer);
    (*wrapper)();
    delete wrapper;
}

int main()
{
    function<void()>* callback = new function<void()>(bind(&foo, 1, 7.5, 8.4f));
    call_agent(callback);
}
```

Simply pass pointers to `std::function<void()>` objects to the `awake` function (and `delete` them after you've called them). `void()` as a template parameter means that the wrapped function should have no return value and accept no parameter, you can tweak that however you like (`int()` would be "int return value and no parameter", `char(short, float)` would be "char return value and accepts a short and a float", etc.)

[`std::bind(Function, args...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) returns a callable object of an unspecified type. The parameters you passed to `bind` are then forwarded to the function. [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) wraps any kind of callable object, including function pointers and the result of an `std::bind` call, so you don't need to worry about the type of the thing you're calling.

What's more, you'll get compile-time errors if you provide incorrect parameters to `bind` instead of having to wade through disassembly to figure out what went wrong. You can also pass composite types to `bind` (structures, unions), and even non-POD types.

Comment: This looks cool! But how can I use it to call from another thread? Do you mean I need to make a Invoke like this: void Invoke(function<void()>*) , then send it to the drawing thread and call it?

Comment: The purpose of `new`ing the object is that you get a pointer to it. You can pass that pointer to the other thread, cast it to a `function<void()>*`, and use the call operator on it. I just edited my answer to show how you'd pass it to a function that accepts a `void*` parameter.

Comment: Sounds great! This seems perfectly solves my problem! Now I'm quite interested in the implementation of std::bind and std::function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is so weird that such a low level problem about calling convention is not solved by assembly or compiler directives, but high level constructs like function objects that only appear in the newest C++ standard.

Comment: @C.R., I get what you're saying, but my answer doesn't address the issue of passing real numbers on the stack: rather, it addresses the issue of calling an arbitrary function with pre-specified parameters on another thread. The most important thing I'd like this answer to teach anyone is to ask questions about problems, not about attempted solutions. :)

Comment: Another problem is, I used some tricks to Invoke class member functions from outside the class(by manually passing "this" pointer) in my previous implementation. Can I do the same with bind and function?

Comment: @user1778496, yes. Pass a pointer to the member function as the first parameter of `bind`, and pass the object pointer as the second parameter (and then pass the method parameters, if any).

Comment: So strange. According to my research, this pointer is passed in the ECX register in g++. How can it call the function with the correct convention?

Comment: @user1778496, it probably does template magic to figure out that the first parameter is a method pointer. It then relies on the compiler to produce the correct code instead of implementing the call logic. That's pretty much the only way to do it without invoking undefined behavior. Besides, you can't treat a method pointer as a function pointer, because methods can be virtual.

Comment: Thanks for your remind. I didn't notice that at all... And I believe this will be a perfect solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @zneak: You are right. I didn't read his comments, which are the real questions.

Answer (score 2):

Change the assembly side to match. Assembly is not bound by calling conventions.

If it's third party assembly, build a proxy function in assembly that moves the parameter around, then jumps to the real function.

Comment: Currently I'm using this prototype: void Invoke(void*proc,int argnum, ...). It wraps the data and passes them to assembly code. With these information, I'm afraid I can't tell the difference between floating points and common arguments. BTW, there is no 3rd party code.